# How do I register genesis custom blocks programmatically in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I am trying to create a theme that uses Genesis custom blocks. I want to be able to register a few blocks programmatically when the theme is installed.

The documentation (https://developer.wpengine.com/genesis-custom-blocks/) says that when you want to add a block programmatically you need to use the add_block function from the Genesis namespace

```
use function Genesis\CustomBlocks\add_block;
add_block( $block_name, $block_config );
```

I did this and nothing is registered.

I have put the add_block function in my theme directory under /blocks/block-test.php.

I cannot figure out why it is not registering.

Comment: https://developer.wpengine.com/genesis-custom-blocks/functions/add_block/

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work. Copied and pasted it.